# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate return invalidate error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, upsert

I'm trying to add comments to this scheme:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema(
{
    ad_id:String,
    comments:
    [
        {
            author: String,
            authorID: Number,
            posted: Date,
            text: String,
            title: String
        }  
    ]
}
```

But if the `ad_id` exists i just want to push the new comment to `comments` basically create a `upsert` query:

```
var query = {'ad_id': req.body.data.ad_ID}
    var doc = {$set:{'ad_id':req.body.data.ad_ID},$push:{'comments':{'author':req.body.data.author,'authorID':req.body.data.uID,'posted':req.body.data.posted
    ,'text':req.body.data.text, 'title':req.body.data.title}}};
    var options = {upsert:true};

    Comments.findOneAndUpdate(query,doc,options, function (err, doc) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(String(err));
            res.send({"foo": String(err)});
        }
        else {
            console.log((doc));
            res.send(doc);
        }
    });
```

But in the get the follwing error :

```
Unable to invalidate a subdocument that has not been added to an array.
```

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: It turns out that I had a data type error that causes that. @piemonkey

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had data type error that causes that.
If anyone encounter that error code make sure that the `data types` match the input.